# File property not showing up as managed metadata in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, managed-property, crawled-property, refiner

In our tenant, we have a library with multiple contentTypes (Document category). Every contentType has one unique Choice column (Document Sub-category.
I added the columns to the index, and mapped them to different managed properties. All properties are showing up in my custom search-center, except for one.

What I tried/found:

- I found the crawled property,
- I mapped the Crawled property to a refinablestring,
- I made sure there were checked-in and approved files with the property,
- I Installed the 'SharePoint search Query tool' and searched for relevant files to see if the crawled
  property shows up
- I compared it to other ContentTypes that also have a choice column (Not the same column) crawled
  metadata.

Any idea why my mapped property does not show up in either the search query tool, or the search center.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the crawled property is include in full_text index and managed property is searchable and wait for full crawl to complete.

Comment: How do i know it is included in the full-text index. I looked at the managed properties and none of them are included in the full-text index, though most of them work.

I cannot do a full crawl, since i'm on SharePoint Online. but i definitely waited more than 72 hours